# Simple compiler question

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm having a problem compiling a multiple-part project. I thought I had included the correct `#ifndef/#define` statements and included header files correctly, but apparently not. When attempting to compile this error came up:

```
[23:18]andrew final_project$:g++ driver2.cpp fish.cpp bay.cpp
ld: duplicate symbol Fish::Fish()  in /var/folders/cc/cc+as-5yHSqg0Jcr+X2+uk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccqNXrPE.o 
and /var/folders/cc/cc+as-5yHSqg0Jcr+X2+uk+++TI/-Tmp-//cc5dOIm5.o for
architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can include more information if necessary, but my two header files (`fish.h` and `bay.h`) are bookended with.

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
...
#endif
```

my two implementation files are `fish.cpp` and `bay.cpp`.

fish.cpp: `#include "fish.h"`

bay.cpp: `#include "bay.h" #include "fish.h"`

My driver program driver2.cpp: `#include "fish.cpp" #include "bay.cpp"`

I assume the problem lies in the fact that bay.cpp includes both fish.h and bay.h, but when I don't include fish.h the "bay" (a grid of fish) is undefined. I would guess the problem isn't too hard, but I can't seem to find a solution.

--Thanks in advance,
  SegFaults McGee

Comment: Every header should be surrounded with unique #ifndef name.

Comment: They are! I just used foo for simplicity's sake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include the .cpp files in `driver2.cpp`. Include `fish.h` and `bay.h` instead.

Comment: +1. In general, if you're ever writing `#include` and `.cpp` on the same line, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Haha thanks for the advice. This is my first time compiling something with more than three files and it shows!